# SHA256 odd hex input

Tags: hash, sha256

I was trying to hash 'abc' as a hex number input on two different sites, but both give different hash.
Later I found out, that one site interprets it as '0abc' and the second one as 'abc0'.

Since I'm finishing my sha256 hashing program, I was wondering which one is correct.

Thank you

Comment: A hexadecimal input must be an even number of characters as it takes two to encode a single byte, the sites made a different arbitrary choice to add an extra 0 to the end or start of the input to make the length valid.  The solution is to not attempt to process invalid input in the first place (i.e 'abc' is not a valid hex string).